# How can I open a GridOut instance of a file in a GridFS in PyMongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, gridfs, launching-application

Let's say I have a pdf file that I want to open in a Python script in the systems's default application for pdfs.

First, if it's kept in the regular file system I would simply open it like this:

```
import os
os.system('Open /Users/Doe/Documents/mypdf.pdf')
```

Second, if I want to store the pdf file in a GridFS, I can write to the GridFS like this:

```
from pymongo import Connection
from gridfs import GridFS
db = Connection().text_database
fs = GridFS(db)
with open('/Users/Doe/Documents/mypdf.pdf') as mypdf: 
    oid = fs.put(mypdf)
```

I can then read the file like this:

```
myfile = fs.get(oid)
```

But how can I do the last step, that is, how can I open the pdf file in the in the systems's default application for pdfs?

EDIT:

Now I am writing the GridOut instance to a temporary file, and then opening that temporary file. It would be nice to skip that extra step of writing to the file system.

```
import tempfile
temp_path = tempfile.mkdtemp()
with open(os.path.join(temp_path, myfile.filename), 'w') as f:
    f.write(myfile.read())
os.system('open {}'.format(os.path.join(temp_path, myfile.filename)))
```

Comment: Did you ever find anything else?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? *Asked by [user3404455](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3404455/user3404455)*

Answer (score 0):

You can only use IPC (interprocess communications). Python GridOut is not IPC by definition. Filesystem is IPC. Or connecting stdout of your program to stdin of your PDF program (if the program supports).